# InetAddress.getLocalHost() resolution on OSX Lion when offline

Tags: java, macos, dns, localhost, osx-lion

Is anyone having issues with Java's InetAddress.getLocalHost() resolution in Java with OSX Lion when working offline (i.e. not connected to internet)?

It would appear that localhost:127.0.0.1 is not resolved at all:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1356)
```

Nothing special in my /etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

I suspect this is not a Java issue, but rather an OSX Lion DNS resolution issue.

Can anyone help?

If this is not the right forum, where can I ask about this?

Any tips on how debug this further at OSX level?

UPDATE 26/10/2011 - This could be JDK bug, the following test:

```
InetAddress addr;
try {
   addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   System.out.println("With localhost access: " + addr);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
   addr = InetAddress.getByName(null);
   System.out.println("With reverse lookup: " + addr);
}
```

Would print the following when offline:

```
With reverse lookup: localhost/127.0.0.1
```

Cheers,
Galder

Comment: What does `ping localhost` in `Terminal.app` show?

Comment: So you are just calling `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` and you get that exception?  Wow.  This is on Java1.6 on Mac OSX 10.7.X?  I seems to work for me.

Comment: Mac OSX 10.7.2 with JDK: java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a way to workaround this issue, just add an alias for localhost to the network interface:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 alias 127.0.0.1
```

Once that's in place, I get no localhost issues any more when offline.