# cannot start Aptana Studio 3 on my Mac offline with java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: macos, aptana

I've been using Aptana Studio for 2 years. I've figured it out, that I cannot start my Aptana Studio 3 offline.
As soon as I try to start my Aptana Studio 3.4.2.201308081805 on my Mac OSX 10.7 (and now it's 10.9) offline, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError will be occurred and Aptana Studio will be quitted. 
This only happens when I open my Aptana Studio 3 offline. When my computer is connected to internet, then I can start the editor without any problem. Even when I go offline after I opened the editor once online, I can still use it.
Does anyone have tips for this?
Hier follows the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-11-04 11:47:38.781
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initializeProperties(Framework.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1396)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.getIPAddress(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.computeNodeAddress(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.<clinit>(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:35)
    ... 12 more
```

Your reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue.  According to the Aptana developers, this isn't a bug in Aptana Studio; it's a problem with the Eclipse OSGI framework.  See here for their report: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7991

This bug affects other applications based on the framework and other people have narrowed it down to a problem with the JVM on Mac OS X.  There is already a question related to this explaining a workaround: [InetAddress.getLocalHost() resolution on OSX Lion when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892609/inetaddress-getlocalhost-resolution-on-osx-lion-when-offline)

The workaround is to create an alias for localhost to the network interface:

`sudo ifconfig en0 alias 127.0.0.1`

I've not tested this yet and can't vouch for what side effects there may be to adding this alias.