# Flash Builder 4.7 crashes only when Wifi is off (OS X 10.9.2)

Tags: eclipse, macos, flash-builder

I'm subscribing to Adobe CC just for FB and Flash Pro. This bug seems undocumented but is hugely annoying. It has not always been this way - it developed over time, and for awhile if I toggled wifi and restarted it would work again. It is definitely not a workspace corruption; I've reinstalled FB, I've tried different workspaces. What happens is that when wifi is on, or as long as the computer is allocated an external IP, Flash Builder 4.7 works. If wifi is off, or if it fails to find a network, FB crashes before it tries to load the workspace.

Interestingly, if I create a wifi network, assigning my own box a 192.168.*.* address, FB launches. But if I turn off wifi while FB is open, it throws an error when I try to save files, and throws another error when I quit, saying it can't save the workspace. It's beyond me why, but FB is obviously failing read/write in the absence of a non-local IP being allocated to the box.

This happens even with a clean install and no projects or dependencies.

Has anyone encountered this one? FWIW, I'm also running Eclipse Helios and Kepler, as well as Flash Builder 4 on the same box for maintaining older code - plus Flash Pro and the rest of the CC without any problems. What is up with FB 4.7 ?! I wish Adobe had just put out a damn Eclipse plugin instead of this pile of **** I'm paying $50 a month for. To be an IDE that fails whenever I can't get online.

I can't upgrade OS X on this box, but I doubt it would make a difference, since this is a Java error of some kind and FB hasn't been updated since 2013 or so anyway. It used to work. Unless I got infected with a worm that's trying to upload things I write, I don't see a reason it stopped unless some perms or base code got corrupted. Any insight would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with localhost domain resolution on OS X. A workaround can be found here:
[InetAddress.getLocalHost() resolution on OSX Lion when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892609/inetaddress-getlocalhost-resolution-on-osx-lion-when-offline)